# ASP.NET MVC 5 hosted on windows 7 local iis listing directory but not diplaying application

Tags: iis, localhost

I have an MVC5 application deployed to my windows 7 local IIS. I have enabled directory browsing and also created an AppPool for the application. I have linked the application to it's AppPool and also tweaked the advanced settings to reflect localService.

When I visit the application, it only displays the directory listing without showing the application.

Would be waiting to read from you.

Answer (score 1):

Re-installing the iis via the command prompt:

- Lunch the command prompt on windows
- Navigate to where you have the .net framework v4.0
- C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis.exe /I
- Verify the appPool pipeline mode is set to integrated
- Check your application, you should be fine.